# Partial Fractions Decomposition, Differentiating between linear and nonlinear

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

My confusion is between
$$\dfrac{(x^2+1)}{(x^3)(x+1)}= A/(x) + (Ax+b)/(x^2) + (Cx+d)/(x^3)$$

or

$$\dfrac{(x^2+1)}{(x^3)(x+1)}= A/(x) + B/(x^2) + C/(x^3)$$

Also in the following case, I think the first version is correct but I could use some clarification:

$$\dfrac{(x^2+1)}{(x)(x^2+1)^2}= (Ax+B)/(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)/(x^2+1)^2 + D/(x)$$

Or

$$\dfrac{(x^2+1)}{(x)(x^2+1)^2}= (Ax+B)/(x^2+1) + (Bx^2+Cx+D)/(x^2+1)^2 + E/(x)$$

Obviously those two things are related, and what I really need is someone to explain how it should be in the general case so I can figure out what the right way should be logically.
From what I've seen the exponents on the outside of the parentheses don't matter and it's the inside ones tat count, but I don't see why it would be like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Multiply both sides of equality by $(x^3)(x+1)$ the common denominator and simplify. Built a system of linear variables for each coefficient of the polynomial You've found ans substitute . You need this fractions:

$$\dfrac{(x^2+1)}{(x^3)(x+1)}= A/x + Bx/x^2 + Cx/x^3+(Dx+f)/(x+1)$$

for the first case

Comment: I know the right way, I dont know why its right.

Comment: @user902834 Solving for the constants that way makes the original equation hold for every $x$ except the zeros of the denominator.  Continuity forces it hold at the other values of $x$ in the equation obtained by clearing the denominator.

Comment: @Hugus Your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right beginning:
$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^3(x+1)}=\frac ax+\frac{b}{x^2}+\frac{c}{x^3}+\frac{d}{x+1}.$$
For your second case your first attempt is the right one.